# How to conditionally disable a button in Vue v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code, every time the condition is true, the disabled is affecting all of the buttons in all the items.

I have searched and couldn't find the proper way of doing it, can someone shed some light please?

The purpose of this is to limit the number of an item that the user can add to the shopping basket by disabling the + button.

```
            <tbody v-for="(item, index) in getMenuItems" :key="index">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>{{ item.name }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="(option, index) in item.options" :key="index" >
                    <td>{{ option.size }}</td>
                    <td>{{ option.price}}</td>
                    <td >
                        <button 
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"
                            type="button"
                            @click="addToBasket( item, option)"
                            :disabled="itemdisabled=='disabled'"
                        >+</button>
                    </td>
                        {{ basket }}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: How do you assign value to `itemdisabled`?

Comment: Maybe you could use a computed property for itemDisabled?

Comment: it looks like you want `item.disabled` instead of `itemdisabled`

Comment: I have a method in 'addToBasket' which tracks the number of items added to the basket like so:

this.basket[this.counter].quantity > this.itemMaxQty ? this.basket[this.counter].disabled = "disabled" : this.basket[this.counter].disabled = "";

Comment: Here's the vue file: https://jsfiddle.net/rmy1x3a9/

Answer (score 7):

You can use `computed` or `methods` to check disabled.

For example:

```
<tbody v-for="(item, index) in getMenuItems" :key="index">
  <tr>
      <td><strong>{{ item.name }}</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(option, index) in item.options" :key="index" >
      <td>{{ option.size }}</td>
      <td>{{ option.price}}</td>
      <td >
          <button 
              class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"
              type="button"
              @click="addToBasket( item, option)"
              :disabled="isDisable(option, index)"
          >+</button>
      </td>
          {{ basket }}
  </tr>
</tbody>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    methods: {
      isDisable(option, index) {
        // check option and index
        // return true - disable, false - active
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: My disable logic works, but the problem is due to the v-for, it disables all of the buttons in the table.

Comment: That's why you need to check `isDisable(option, index)`, base on option and index, you only return true on item you want to be disabled

Comment: Hey thanks @ittus, I got it working, but is it an efficient way of doing it having to loop through the basket on every render?

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokndf4r/)